# Prolog Can't get to the predicate

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, swi-prolog-for-sharing

The prolog is supposed to find the order of five statements statements. Everything is working fine but when i call the query  `solution([A, B, C, D, E])` I get a sandbox error like this:

The Error:

```
Sandbox restriction!
Could not derive which predicate may be called from
      call(C)
      all(schoolgirl,[A,B,C,D,E])
      solution([A,B,C,D,E])
```

Full Prolog Program:

```
all(_,[]).
all(Pred, [X|Xs]):-
    P =..[Pred,X],
    call(P),
    all(Pred,Xs).
distinct([]).
distinct([X|Xs]):- 
    not(member(X, Xs)), distinct(Xs).
x0r(A, B):- 
    A, not(B).
x0r(A, B):-
    not(A), B.

schoolgirl(betty).
schoolgirl(ethel).
schoolgirl(joan).
schoolgirl(kitty).
schoolgirl(mary).

betty(Snd,Trd):- 
    x0r(Snd=kitty, Trd=betty).
ethel(Fst, Snd):- 
    x0r(Fst=ethel, Snd=joan).
joan(Trd, Fith):- 
    x0r(Trd=joan, Fith=ethel).
kitty(Snd, Forth):- 
    x0r(Snd=kitty, Forth=mary).
mary(Forth, Fst):- 
    x0r(Forth=mary, Fst-betty).

solution([Fst, Snd, Trd, Forth, Fith]):-
    all(schoolgirl, [Fst,Snd, Trd, Forth, Fith]),
    distinct([Fst, Snd, Trd, Forth, Fith]),
    betty(Snd, Trd),
    ethel(Fst, Snd),
    joan(Trd, Fith),
    kitty(Snd, Forth),
    mary(Forth, Fst).
```

The Call is

```
solution([A, B, C, D, E])
```

Comment: Sandbox, I take indicates that you are using SWISH. I am not a SWISH user so can't help you there. Try installing SWI-Prolog and doing from the command line. I suspect that it is `call/1` causing the problem but that is a pure guess. And once again the duck is not told.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like a commenter said, this seems to be a particular restriction when using SWI-Prolog's browser-based SWISH system (https://swish.swi-prolog.org/). It doesn't want you to use `call/1` with terms that it doesn't know enough about.

Fortunately, you can give it a bit more information: You use `call/1` in the following context:

```
P =..[Pred,X],
call(P),
```

That is, for a call to a predicate `Pred` with exactly one argument `X`. There is a more direct syntax for this:

```
call(Pred, X)
```

and this is enough to make the error go away, and to make SWISH willing to run your program. (In fact this syntax is a bit more general because it takes exactly one *additional* argument to be added to the ones already in `Pred`, so `call(f(a), b)` would call the goal `f(a, b)`.)

Your query will now die with a somewhat obscure error:

```
procedure `A-B' does not exist
Reachable from:
      call(_1690-betty)
      not(A-betty)
      x0r(A=mary,B-betty)
      mary(A,B)
      solution(A)
```

You have a typo in the definition of your `mary/2` predicate.